# Excel Vba getting value of cell and setting a string

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set a string as a certain letter based on the value of a cell. The cell should only have the values, "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4". If the cell is "P1" then I want to set the string "products2" as "a", if its "P2" I want "products2" set as "b" ...

Here is the code, which will get the correct value for the cell, but wont use it to set the products2.

```
Dim Products As String
Dim Products2 As String

      Products = wash.offset(1, 3).Value

            If Products = P1 Then
                Products2 = "a"
            ElseIf Products = P2 Then
                MsgBox "we got here"
                Products2 = "b"
            End If

            MsgBox "products2 = " & Products2
```

Comment: seems to work here. Can you show how you set wash and P1/P2?

Comment: Dim wash As Range. P1 and P2 are just values in the cell, I didn't set them as anything

Comment: I think you mean "P1" rather than P1. But -- what do you want to do in other cases (e.g. "P4")?

Comment: Yes, I just haven't got to it yet, I tried "P1" it also didn't work.

Comment: Btw, the current value of wash.offset(1, 3) is "P2"

Comment: ahh ok. So what value is in P1 and P2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version that will do what you want, and extend it to P3 etc. I had to set `wash` to some location to get the code to work. It assumes that the value in the cell you are accessing is of the form `Pi` where `i` is an integer. It gets the value of `i`, shifted down by 1, then obtains gets the letter in the alphabet shifted by `i` (so "a" for 0, "b" for 1, etc.)

```
Sub ProdString()
    Dim Products As String
    Dim Products2 As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wash as Range

    Set wash = Range("A1")
    Products = wash.Offset(1, 3).Value
    Products = Mid(Trim(Products), 2) 'strip off the "P"
    i = Val(Trim(Products)) - 1
    Products2 = Chr(i + Asc("a"))
    MsgBox "Products2 = " & Products2

End Sub
```

Comment: This keeps giving me the value "b"  for products2 regardless of what products is. Thank you though, this is getting me closer to what I had imagined

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. If `D2` (which is `wash.Offset(1,3)` if `wash` is `A1`) is P4, I see "Products2 = d" displayed. If I change the value in that cell to P5 and rerun the sub I see "Products2 = e" displayed. Are you sure that you have the right cell? Maybe test it by adding the line `MsgBox wash.Offset(1,3).Address'

Comment: Nevermind, GOT IT TO WORK! Thank you very much, I had to set i as something else (I was already using that variable) and forgot to change one part.

Answer (score 1):

The way it exists right now, it is trying to compare `products` to a variable rather than a string

```
Dim Products As String
Dim Products2 As String

Products = cstr(trim(wash.offset(1, 3).Value))

If Products = "P1" Then
    Products2 = "a"
ElseIf Products = "P2" Then
    MsgBox "we got here"
    Products2 = "b"
End If

MsgBox "products2 = " & Products2
```

A good way to extend it so it easily covers "P1" through "P4" would be to use a `select` statement as follows:

```
Products = CStr(Trim(wash.Offset(1, 3).value))

Select Case Products
    Case "P1":
        Products2 = "a"
    Case "P2":
        Products2 = "b"
    Case "P3":
        Products2 = "c"
    Case "P4":
        Products2 = "d"
End Select

MsgBox "products2 = " & Products2
```

It's a lot easier to scan while reading.

Comment: Setting `Products = "P2"` and running the code gives me a msgbox saying `products2 = b`

Comment: maybe the value isnt coming in as a string to compare try Products = cstr(trim(wash.offset(1, 3).Value))

Answer (score 0):

My attempt

```
Function StrOut(strIn As String)
StrOut = Chr(96 + CLng(Replace(strIn, "P", vbNullString)))
End Function
```

*test*

```
Sub TestDaCode()
Debug.Print StrOut("P1")
Debug.Print StrOut("P2")
End Sub
```